# Why doesn't Rust support trait objects with associated constants?

Tags: rust, trait-objects, associated-const

I know it's because of [object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety):

> Object safe traits can be the base trait of a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/types/trait-object.html). A trait is *object safe* if it has the following qualities (defined in [RFC 255](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0255-object-safety.md)):
>
> - ...
> - It must not have any associated constants.

But if an associated constant is declared with a **specific value**, why does Rust still not support it? Here is an example:

```
trait Trait {
    const A: i32 = 64;
}

fn fun(t: Box<dyn Trait>) -> bool {
    return  true;
}
```

I want to use a function to return a constant value, and deliberately omit the `&self` parameter, but it still doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
trait Trait {
    fn getA() -> i32 {
        64
    }
}

fn fun(t: Box<dyn Trait>) -> bool {
    return  true;
}
```

Is there a low level reason why Rust doesn't support it? Or is it just because of the RFC rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They aren't object-safe, because the constant value may differ for trait implementers:

```rust
trait Foo {
    const A: i32 = 4;
}

impl Foo for bool {
    const A: i32 = 5;
}
```

Which value should `(dyn Foo)::A` produce?

By using `dyn Foo` the original type is erased, and without a pointer/reference to a `dyn Foo` value there is no vtable that could be consulted. The same problem exists for a trait method without a `self` parameter.

You need regular generics for this:

```
trait Trait {
    const A: i32 = 64;
}

fn fun<T: Trait>(t: T) -> i32 {
    T::A
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you understand why a trait cannot have an associated type or constant in order to be object safe. The question of why a trait can't have an associated constant with a specific value is simple: just as a function definition in the trait definition is merely a default implementation and can be overridden by implementors of the trait, the value of an associated constant in the trait definition can also be overridden by implementors. Therefore this value would be unknown for a given `dyn Trait`, which — for the same reason that associated types make a trait object unsafe — makes `Trait` object unsafe.

Answer (score -1):

The trait `Trait` can't be made into an object. So you must change the function parameter for `fn fun()`:

```
trait Trait {
    const A: i32 = 64;
}

fn fun(t: impl Trait) -> bool {
    // do something with the Trait implementation t
    true
}

struct WithTrait;

impl Trait for WithTrait {
    const A: i32 = 64;
}
```

As soon you have an object implementing `Trait` you can pass it to the `fun()` function:
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f23577da9902649a7ea4e64affec7e7f)

Similar example can be found in the Rust reference under [Associated Constants Examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-constants-examples)